# How can I put the same research on progress presented in multiple conferences on a CV?

Tags: cv, presentation

If someone is presenting their same “research on progress” in multiple meetings and conferences, how can I strategically plan for each presentation such that each presentation is looking unique on a CV?

Or is it even necessary to make it look unique on the CV? If making each presentation unique is not a good/ethical idea, what is the best way to list all presentations on the CV without giving the impression that presentations are listed to increase the length of the CV?

Comment: If it looks like "padding" the resume it will hurt you.

Comment: Researchers routinely present on the same material for multiple audiences. Reporting these talks is not padding your resume -- you are presumably reaching more people by giving more talks.

Comment: You are allowed to give the same talk more than once, at least in mathematics... :)

Comment: ... especially, if you are _invited_ to give the same (or similar) talk more than once, that's a positive, in mathematics. Apparently in other subjects, "giving a talk" is akin to a (status-enhancing) journal publication, so you can't get credit more than one time? Crazy.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I received divided opinions on this topic, I would like to hear more from other people as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my field, it's usual to present work in progress. Depending on how long it takes, it might be presented at 1-3 meetings.

Now, some meetings in my field ask you to assert "*I haven't presented this work elsewhere*," and others don't. Nevertheless, the general expectation is that you aren't submitting identical abstracts to multiple places.

So, what would look odd/"padding" to me would be seeing identical titles in multiple conferences. Again, norms in your field might be different, but you would expect to see the work evolve over time.

At least if you were in my field I'm ***not*** saying just change the title, but what I am saying is a natural evolution of a few abstracts over time is fine.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my comment that obvious padding is hurtful and easily recognized, I suggest that you do the opposite. What you are describing as work in progress, which is, in itself, a valuable thing in a CV.

I suggest that you list the topic of the research once and under it (perhaps using indentation) list the conferences and meetings in which the progress has been reported. This is honest and also shows continued interest in what you are doing. The "progress" isn't separate completed works. I'd suggest that faking it won't help.

Comment: I would be surprised to see this organization on a CV (and also question its maintainability as an organizational strategy). I would expect to see a chronological list of venues at which you've spoken, with the titles under which you gave the talks.

Answer (score 4):

You should not worry about reporting each talk you give, even if it is on the same topic (and with the same materials) as a talk you gave in a different venue. You are presumably speaking to a different audience, and each presentation thus expands the impact of your work.

If you are in a field where conference presentations opportunities are tied to conference-reviewed-and-accepted publications, you should have separate sections of the CV for the conference publications and for conference talks.